# How to disable curly braces replacement in messages in spring mvc validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have such field annotated by @Pattern

final public class Branch{

```
@Pattern( regexp = "([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})[0-9]{8}", message = "Inn should be validated by pattern \"{regexp}\". Check branch settings" )
private String INN;
```

}

In spring form:erros tag

```
   <form:errors path="*"/>
```

if I input wrong INN field I got violation message

```
Inn should be validated by pattern ([0-9][Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@4a5b4234[1-9][Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@4a5b4234|[1-9][Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@4a5b4234[0-9][Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@4a5b4234)[0-9]{8}.. Check branch settings
```

Spring replaces curly braces in my regexp with other objects.
For example, {1} replaced by Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@4a5b4234
How to disable this annoyng behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to escape the `{regexp}` part with simple quotes, as well (`\"'{regexp}'\"`) to make Spring ignore it:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})[0-9]{8}", message = "Inn should be validated by pattern \"'{regexp}'\". Check branch settings")
```